# C programming - Confusion regarding curly braces

Tags: c, scope

The following code is for replacing multiple consecutive spaces into 1 space. Although I manage to do it, I am confused in the use of curly braces.

This one is actually running fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int ch, lastch;
lastch = 'a';
while((ch = getchar())!= EOF)
{

    if(ch == ' ')
    {
        if (lastch != ' ')
        putchar(ch);


    }
    else
        putchar(ch);
        lastch = ch;

}
}
```

But I can't figure out why this one isn't, by only putting curly braces within the inner loop and else statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int ch, lastch;
lastch = 'a';
while((ch = getchar())!= EOF)
{

    if(ch == ' ')
    {
        if (lastch != ' ')
        {
            putchar(ch);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        putchar(ch);
        lastch = ch;
    }
}
}
```

Can I not enclosed a loop within a loop with curly braces? I've read that the second one would be a good practice to make it readable, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both the `then` and `else` branches of the if-statement contain at most one statement. So, if you don't surround the statements in curly braces, then only the first `putchar()` will be executed in the `else` branch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference between the two is the scope of the `else`. Without the braces, it spans until the end of the full statement, which is the next `;`, i.e the next line:

```
else
    putchar(ch); /* end of else */
lastch = ch;     /* outside of if-else */
```

With the braces, it covers the `lastch` assignment too.

The same applies to the `if` statement, but there you have a single line so it makes no difference.

Comment: I feel so dumb. The lastch=ch; should be outside those braces. Thank you for clarifying that!

Answer (score 3):

Any control structure (`if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, etc.) operates on a **block** of code. Blocks are usually denoted by curly braces (`{}`), but if those are omitted, a **single statement** acts as the block. Note that unlike in Python, for example, indentation has no meaning in C, it's just a convince to make the code more readable.

Having said that, let's examine your `else` block:

```
else
    putchar(ch);
    lastch = ch;
```

Since there are no curly braces here, this block is actually equal to the following:

```
else
{
    putchar(ch);
}
lastch = ch;
```

And not to the block in your second code snippet. Here, the indentation of `lastch = ch` did help us understand the code, it was confusing due to bad indentation that made it seem as though it was part of the `else` block when in fact it was not.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize that lastch = ch; is inside those braces.